# MySQL char & varchar character sets & storage sizes

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, sqldatatypes

Wondering how much actual storage space will be taken up by these two datatypes, as the MySQL documentation is slightly unclear on the matter.

> CHAR(M)   M × w bytes, 0 <= M <= 255, where w is the number of bytes
> required for the maximum-length character in the character set
>
> VARCHAR(M), VARBINARY(M)  L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 – 255
> bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes

This seems to imply to me that, given a utf8-encoded database, a CHAR will always take up 32 bits per character, whilst a VARCHAR will take between 8 and 32 depending on the actual byte length of the characters stored. Is that correct? Or does a VARCHAR imply an 8-bit character width, and storing multi-octet UTF8 characters actually consumes multiple 'characters' from the VARCHAR? Or does the VARCHAR also always store 32 bits per character? So many possibilities.

Not something I've ever had to worry this much about before, but I'm starting to hit in-memory temp table size limits and I don't necessarily want to have to increase MySQL's available pool (for the second time).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`CHAR` and `VARCHAR` both count characters. Both of them count the maximum storage that they might require given the character encoding and length. For ASCII, that's 1 byte per character. For UTF-8, that's 3 bytes per character (not 4 as you'd expect, because [MySQL's Unicode support is limited](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) for some reason, and it doesn't support any Unicode characters which would require 4 bytes in UTF-8). So far, `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` are the same.

Now, `CHAR` just goes ahead and reserves this amount of storage.

`VARCHAR` instead allocated 1 or 2 bytes, depending on whether this maximum storage is < 256 or ≥ 256. And the actual amount of space occupied by the entry is these one or two bytes, plus the amount of space actually occupied by the string.

Interestingly, this makes 85 a magic number for UTF-8 `VARCHAR`:

- `VARCHAR(85)` uses 1 byte for the length because the maximum possible length of 85 UTF-8 characters is 3 × 85 = 255.
- `VARCHAR(86)` uses 2 byte for the length because the maximum possible length of 86 UTF-8 characters is 3 × 86 = 258.

Comment: To add to that, MySQL's `utf8` storage is not only crippled, it's not your standard UTF-8 either. `utf8` encoded strings are stored using roughly twice the storage of regular UTF-8 encoded strings, making it even more inefficient.

Comment: @deceze I wasn't aware of that. Do you have any details or reference about that?

Comment: I wish I did, but the documentation isn't saying much about it. There was a recent question here about dumping the database where data was dumped in binary-as-is though, which is where this is very apparent.

Comment: thanks guys, this sheds some good light on it. Interesting about the 85 char length under UTF8 - so basically, the usual varchar(255) in a utf8 encoded database isn't saving you any space at all?

Comment: It looks like it's more complicated than that. For example, [InnoDB has two different row formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-physical-record.html) (`COMPACT` and `REDUNDANT`) so the space occupied by a row depends on which one is in use. It's no longer as simple as it once was when the only storage engine commonly used was MyISAM. Anyway, a 1-byte difference it negligeable anyway. You're way more likely to be concerned about the maximum length of a key in InnoDB, which is 768 bytes. So a UTF-8 VARCHAR(256) cannot be part of a key. A UTF-8 VARCHAR(255) field *can* be a key.

Comment: Ah, the plot thickens.. good to know. I've also noticed there's a "utf8mb4" charset available in later versions of MySQL, which is a fix for the gimped utf8 charset they'd been using up until that point.